# p7zip-desktop: How to specify temporary path for compression?

Tags: command-line, 7zip

Anyone help me to supply the temporary path that is used during compressing the files using p7zip-desktop?

I have installed p7zip-desktop as snap install, and I guess "/tmp" is default temporary path. I want to change it to some other directory.

I tried setting "-w [PATH]" in the parameter input (see below image), but I am not sure whether it's working or not.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The p7zip-desktop will use `/tmp/snap-private-tmp/snap.p7zip-desktop/tmp` as the default temp folder. If you put `-w [PATH]` as you suggested, no, it doesn't work. I tried putting `-w /home/alan/temp` (a folder I made) and it doesn't get used. It still uses the default location.

Looking further at the documentation, the "Parameters" section is limited in what you can specify.

---

Parameters
Allows you to specify parameters for compression. See the -m (Method) switch description for more details. Omit the -m prefix (as in -m switch) when using this dialog box.

Examples

```
  f=delta:4
```

uses Delta:4 filter (if you want to compress WAV files).

```
  f=bcj2
```

uses BCJ2 filter (for x86 executables).

---

According to the documentation on [this mirror](http://web.mit.edu/outland/arch/i386_rhel4/build/p7zip-current/DOCS/MANUAL/switches/method.htm), it's only used for setting the compression method.

Edit: I now note you've asked the upstream developer on a [github issue](https://github.com/ErnyTech/p7zip/issues/21). That's probably the best place for this question.

Comment: Thanks for analysing further and letting me know the actual temp path used by p7zip-desktop. Yeah, i've raised in github as well just to know whether changing path is supported at all.